# Filled ImageViews with images from internet and it is very slow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

In a ViewController have "N" UImagesViews that are filled with images from the internet, but sometimes it takes too long or slow to appear 
Do you know any tool to make my app faster ?
Thanks for your advices

Comment: Have you tried loading one at a time?  IE:  Load one ImageView, and only move onto loading the next once the first has finished?

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you are doing. But the obvious solution is to do the downloading in the background.

Comment: No, I haven't, I load all images together:/

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

From the GitHub page:

> This library provides a category for UIImageView with support for remote images coming from the web.

Comment: Or, if you're using AFNetworking, it provides a similar category, with out the busy spinner though.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I use AFNetworking and now my app is so fast!!! thanks thanks ... all is perfect XD